# Keep WinForms buttons centered automatically

Tags: winforms

I have a form with several buttons that I hide and show as needed. Is there a simple way to keep the visible buttons centered, side by side (maybe using one of the container controls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off the **`anchor`** in a direction and setting **`dock`** to none will keep the control centered

Hope, this is what you need...!!